# KeyError: "None of [Index(['5', '22', '25', '12',..],\n dtype='object', length=610)] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, eda

Trying to strip a certain part but throw an error "None of index in the columns"

Dataset  :

[image: Here's an ss of the dataset]

Code snippets :

```
df4 = df[df["Rating"].notna()]
df4  = df4[df4["Rating"].str.strip("%").astype(int)]
df4
```

Error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([ 36,  97,  97,  95,  96,  86,  89,  95,  92,  95,\n            ...\n            100,  92,  99, 100,  97, 100,  82,  97,  80,  97],\n           dtype='int64', length=335)] are in the [columns]"
```

```
df5 = df[df["Experience"].str.strip("years experience")]
df5
```

Error :

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['5', '22', '25', '12', '33', '13', '15', '5', '12', '13',\n       ...\n       '20', '28', '26', '11', '13', '19', '15', '14', '40', '41'],\n      dtype='object', length=610)] are in the [columns]"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not do operations like this; 
`df4  = df4[df4["Rating"].str.strip("%").astype(int)]`
try to use `apply` in suitable manner. for example; 
`df4 = df4["Rating"].apply(lambda x: x.strip("%")).astype(int)`
And, 
your first line `df[df["Rating"].notna()]` works because `df["Rating"].notna()` returns boolean series and outer `df[]` operate on a that series such a way that remain records that give `True` for the series.